# Filling in the screen with a diamond grid with pure javascript (jsfiddle is available)

Tags: javascript

Those who solve this will get 150 reputation points once im eligible for a bounty.

https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/xzxe6y5k/

As you can see in the jsfiddle I did some trigonometric calculations to figure out the exact position for the adjacent placements.

The following formula gives me the exact positioning:

`elem.offsetHeight * Math.cos(degrees converted into radians) + elem.offsetTop`

`elem.offsetWidth * Math.cos(degrees converted into radians) + elem.offsetLeft`

Of course the same thing is also possible by getting the vertex points, the code would just be larger. Here a small example:

```
elem.offsetLeft + elem.offsetWidth
elem.offsetTop + elem.offsetHeight
```

Anyways, I figure that automatic placement is pretty hard. I mean **I am trying to achieve something like in the image below**: http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/dg.png

**Question:** So how can I make the diamond grid spread to the full height and width of the screen / container from the center? Not a loop from left to right and top to bottom but starting from the center in a somewhat circular way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the screen filled with two while loops. For now I used some static margins, so the spacings are not perfect, but I guess your `computePosition` function can help with generating the right spacings between the diamonds.

https://jsfiddle.net/xzxe6y5k/3/

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('grid'), diamond = wrapper.children, newDiamond, prevDiamond, evenRow = true;

function createDiamonds() {
  while (!newDiamond || newDiamond.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < window.innerHeight) {
    evenRow = !evenRow;
   prevDiamond = newDiamond;
   newDiamond = wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    
    if (prevDiamond) {
        newDiamond.style.top = prevDiamond.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + 10 - (newDiamond.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2) + 'px';
      
      if (evenRow) {
        newDiamond.style.left = diamond[0].getBoundingClientRect().left + newDiamond.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 + 7 + 'px';
      }
    }
    
    while (newDiamond.getBoundingClientRect().right < window.innerWidth) {
      prevDiamond = newDiamond;
      newDiamond = wrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      newDiamond.style.left = prevDiamond.getBoundingClientRect().right + 10 + 'px';
      newDiamond.style.top = prevDiamond.style.top;
    }
  }
}

createDiamonds();
```

```css
#grid div {
  background: black;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: You are using a totally different method with getBoundingClientRect. Really interesting.

Comment: Nice effect with the overlapping diamonds